# DNN 7 call / consume services framework service in module

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, asp.net-web-api

I created a simple service using the DNN 7 services framework.

The service only has a simple method at the moment

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage HelloWorld()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World!");
    }
```

I access this from going to

```
http://localhost:81/DesktopModules/dnn_Service_Test/API/Welcome/HelloWorld
```

I have also created a module for the dnn site and I now wish to call the service methods from the module. How do I go about doing that?

The service is separate as I will also be calling the service from a mobile app and yes both service and module are on the same dnn site.

Comment: The question is very unclear, are you asking how you call your web-api methods?

Comment: Just modified the question I am asking, does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

After registering your Service *Controller* class, you can just start calling your method as web methods, using Get or Post.

Example how it can be used from javascript:

```
 var sf = $.ServicesFramework(<%=ModuleId %>);
 var url = sf.getServiceRoot('dnn_Service_Test') + 'Welcome/HelloWorld';
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url ,
        data: '',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            ....do something here....
         },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```